# Apex SOQL Strange Behavior skips spaces

Tags: soql

I have a custom object under the account entity (master-detail). This object (System Codes) has 3  fields (Account, Code, Line).  I perform a query in inspector (or in dev. console - the results are the same) to find aggregate results:
select count(id), code__c, line__c from SystemCodes__c group by code__c, line__c.
This query returns records like:

| # of records | Code | Line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 502 | 98 | test gig |
| 200 | 98 | test gig |

The second row's line field is "test  gig" (double space).
However, when i try to query in order to view those 200 records, i get no data returned!!!
select id, customerId__c, code__c, line__c where line = 'test  gig'

The strange thing is, i logged into salesforce, found a record that has a line with the string 'test  gig' (double space between test and gig), copied and pasted it in the query and records were returned! Has anybody faced again this situation? I found out that the issue is related to the double space probably since while selecting with like 'test%' records were returned, but when i selected with like 'test %', no rows were returned. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the unicode values of the string -- there could be a whitespace character like a non-breaking space or something else, and they're not the same as a Spacebar space character.

Comment: Thanks David, i will check it.